# Retrieve all rows that were inserted today

Tags: symfony, dql

I am trying to retrieve all rows that were inserted today (only DATE, not time) in my mysql db.

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT md
               FROM YtBundle:Mood md
               WHERE md.created_at = CURRENT_DATE()
               ");
$moods = $query->getResult();
```

I have inserted a test row created at 2013-04-24 02:00:00 and unfortunately I get no results. If I change "=" with ">" it successfully works OK. Any idea about why is this happening ? It appears that all entries inserted in today's date have a +1 difference after running the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT md
               FROM YtBundle:Mood md
               WHERE md.created_at >= CURRENT_DATE()
               ");

$moods = $query->getResult();
```

Column created_at is stored in a TIMESTAMP column so CURRENT_DATE = '2013-04-24 00:00:00', and it's not equal to '2013-04-24 02:00:00'

Comment: So every request for WHERE .... ends in being greater than CURRENT_DATE which is '2013-04-24 00:00:00' ? This makes sense.

Comment: That's it. It works for current day but you can manage a BETWEEN clause with, for example '2013-04-24 00:00:00' and '2013-04-24 23:59:59' if you request on a past day...

Comment: It's worth noting that using CURRENT_DATE makes a query uncacheable. Something like `... WHERE md.created_at >= 2013-04-24` should be cachable.